# Oracle Redaction and Definer's Rights Stored Procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rights, redaction

I create a data Redaction policy for a field EMAIL and in the expression statment is the exception for the **Data base owner user**. It works perfectly :)

This field is in a insert-select statmement in a trigger, so when the trigger is executed I get the error  ORA-28081: Insufficient privileges - the command references a redacted object

To prevent this error I moved the insert-select statement to a Stored Procedure that, by default, has Definer Rights. But I still have the ORA-28081 error.

Why this do not solve if the procedure is executed with the rights of the **Data base owner user** ?